# How to get an output similar to remix in solc, woth opcodes + comments from source

Tags: solidity, solc, compilation

I would like to compile my contracts and to get an output with the opcodes in detail (not just assembly) but with references to the solidity source code at each line. This is the output one gets by default when using the [Remix editor](https://remix.ethereum.org/) and cliking on "details", but I can't find a way to get that using the `solc` binary: I get either assembly with comments using `--asm` or opcodes without comments `--opcodes`. Can I do that?

EDIT: to clarify, what I mean by assembly is something like

      `tag_11
        /* "pot.sol":5259:5263  myid */
      dup3
        /* "pot.sol":5265:5271  result */
      dup3
        /* "pot.sol":5283:5284  0 */
      0x0
        /* "pot.sol":5273:5285  new bytes(0) */`

and what I mean by opcodes is something like

`SWAP1             contract Coucou{\n    address ...
      DIV           contract Coucou{\n    address ...
      PUSH FFFFFFFF         contract Coucou{\n    address ...
      AND           contract Coucou{\n    address ...
      DUP1          contract Coucou{\n    address ...
      PUSH 26121FF0         contract Coucou{\n    address ...`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by assembly vs opcodes. You have the --abi option, that outputs the contract's ABI, and --bin  for the binary,

Moreover if you just type  `solc` in your console, you'll see all the options available. In my installation, it shows the following:

```
Output Components:
  --ast                AST of all source files.  
  --ast-json           AST of all source files in JSON format.
  --ast-compact-json   AST of all source files in a compact JSON format.
  --asm                EVM assembly of the contracts.
  --asm-json           EVM assembly of the contracts in JSON format.
  --opcodes            Opcodes of the contracts.
  --bin                Binary of the contracts in hex.
  --bin-runtime        Binary of the runtime part of the contracts in hex.
  --clone-bin          Binary of the clone contracts in hex.
  --abi                ABI specification of the contracts.
  --hashes             Function signature hashes of the contracts.
  --userdoc            Natspec user documentation of all contracts.
  --devdoc             Natspec developer documentation of all contracts.
  --metadata           Combined Metadata JSON whose Swarm hash is stored on-chain.
  --formal             Translated source suitable for formal analysis.
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer. I clarified in my question what I mean by "assembly" vs "opcodes".

Answer (score 0):

Just with `solc` cannot do it itself. You need to work with `srcmap-runtime`.
You can run the command like:

`solc --pretty-json --combined-json srcmap-runtime YourContract.sol`

Then you will get something like:

`"srcmap-runtime" : "26:184:0:-;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;137:71;;8:9:-1;5:2;;;30:1;27;20:12;5:2;137:71:0;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;70:57;;8:9:-1;5:2;;;30:1;27;20:12;5:2;70:57:0;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;137:71;175:4;198:3;;191:10;;137:71;:::o;70:57::-;118:2;112:3;:8;;;;70:57;:::o"`

The notation is documented here : https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/miscellaneous.html#source-mappings